# displaying UIBarButton Title on it's image

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to make an custom UIBarButton which display an image and a title and I have done this so far :

[image]

What I want to do is to display the title which is 5 on the shoping cart image and not beside it.

This is the code that I have written :

```
let shopingCartBTN = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
//btnShowMenu.setImage(self.defaultMenuImage(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
shopingCartBTN.setImage(UIImage(named: "shopingCarBarIcon"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
shopingCartBTN.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "shopingCarBarIcon")
shopingCartBTN.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
shopingCartBTN.setTitle("5", forState: .Normal)
shopingCartBTN.addTarget(self, action: "", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
let customBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: shopingCartBTN)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;
```

So ,How should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to increase the width of `Button`

```
let shopingCartBTN = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
//btnShowMenu.setImage(self.defaultMenuImage(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
shopingCartBTN.setImage(UIImage(named: "shopingCarBarIcon"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
shopingCartBTN.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "shopingCarBarIcon")
shopingCartBTN.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 30)//Just increase the width of button
shopingCartBTN.setTitle("5", forState: .Normal)
shopingCartBTN.addTarget(self, action: "", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
let customBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: shopingCartBTN)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;
```

Comment: @donalddraper have you try this?